# Why aren't my isometric objects where I think they are?

Tags: c#, monogame, tiled, monogame-extended

## Background

I am creating an isometric RPG using Tiled and Monogame. My goal is to have relatively elaborate terrain and movement, with my vision for the overworld being much like the now-venerable Megaman Battle Network franchise. As such, by world must be 3D and simply drawn on top of an isometric map assembled from tiles.

## Quirks

The Monogame.Extended system for drawing Tiled maps does so mostly on its own, though I have elected to draw a layer at a time and render any sprites I need to between the layer draw calls. The layers do not use the SpriteBatch I have configured to draw movable sprites, and just take a translation. I've managed to become decently adept at navigating it to convenient locations.

## The Issue

Wikipedia says that for a good isometric scene, you want to rotate 45 degrees around Z and something like 32 degrees around what in my system is X. In my case, the resulting transformation does not seem to match the map image, so I am using an angle of approximately 52 degrees around X, which matches up fairly well. However, while the map itself can be perfectly aligned to the collision system, and I'm able to walk around the edges perfectly, objects within the map seem oddly placed. Some of this may be due to my incorrect handling of the Z (world upward) index, but it seems more than that. When I align the image so that it lines up with them instead of the edges of the map, their sizes seem subtly incorrect - I have found, for instance, that if my X rotation is negative, the objects (which are distant) seem slightly smaller than how they are drawn. I could be misreading that, however.

EDIT: The only distortion, if there is indeed any, seems to be in the viewport's Y direction. I collide where I expect to horizontally.

## My Assumption

I believe this may simply be a camera issue - perhaps the default camera is not orthographic or something?  I don't really know the way to fix that if so, and if not, I'm mystified by what is going on.

Comment: The angle to get the isometric projection is not 32, it is aprox 35.264. Also, notice: 35.264 + 270 = 360 - 54.736. Those must be your aprox 52 degrees.

Comment: That explains a lot.I still need to figure out why things are spaced wrong vertically, but at least the angles make slightly more sense.